# Loader wheel image not displaying while jquery loop function processing

Tags: jquery, dom, html-select, loader

There are about 20-30K select options i have to process in a loop - what i want is to display a loader .gif wheel while it is processing in a loop. I can see that it takes 5-7 seconds !! but i dont see the wheel? If i place a breakpoint in the dev tools i see the wheel at the desired place. But without the breakpoint its like the loop is dead and after 5 seconds it renders the select box ?? Does it have something to do with the DOM?

```
<img src="wheel.jpg" id="wheel" style="display:none;"/>


jquery->
$('#wheel').css({'display':'block'});

loop through a combo box and add or remove <options> from it (no XHR calls)

$('#wheel').css({'display':'none'});
```

Anyone?

Comment: Does it work without the loop?

Comment: @MathiasDewelde i didn try - but i guess i wouldnt see it anyway. May be with the breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

> - **demo:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/dynamic-variables-and-javascript-loops-and-checks/

```
$(function(){

    // ensure the wheel is visible before starting the job
    $('#wheel').fadeIn(500, function(){

        var selects = $('select').size();

        $('select').each(function(i, item){

        //simulating the hard job...
        var options = $(this).find('option').size();
        $(this).find('option').each(function(i, item){
            $(this).text('b');
            if(options==i+1){
                selects--;
            }
        });

        // hiding the wheel when finished
        if (0 == selects) {
            $('#wheel').hide();
        }
    });
    });
});
```